# Retrieving text beginning with specific alphabet from the text file and displaying it in textbox

Tags: c#

I am creating a console application that will take names as an input and will store it in a text file and then i want to retrieve the names beginning with A.

The console application has two textboxes and two buttons. By hitting button1 the text entered in the textbox1 will be copied in the text file, and by clicking button2 U would like to retrieve the name beginning with A and display it in textbox2.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("d:\\demo.txt");
    txt.Write(textBox1.Text);
    txt.Close();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText("d:\\demo.txt");    
}
```

I know how to retrieve the entire data of the text file by using

```
textBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText("d:\\demo.txt");
```

Please help me to retrieve the names beginning with A.

Comment: how is the names written in the text file?

Comment: TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("d:\\demo.txt");
        txt.Write(textBox1.Text);

Comment: `txt.Write` seems like a very bad choice. You better use `WriteLine` otherwise, when you read the file, you won't know where each name begins or ends.

Comment: `Console Apps don't have Buttons` also start reading up on the `string.Substring()` method.. please show what you have tried in reference to reading the file and checking the position

Answer (score 0):

Change `Write` to `WriteLine` and then you can read each name as a separate line. When you do, check the first letter with `StartsWith`. If it starts with an `a`, append it to `textbox2` using `+=`:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter("d:\\demo.txt");
    txt.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
    txt.Close();
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string line;
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"d:\\demo.txt"); 

    while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
    {  
        if (line.ToLower().StartsWith("a"))
        {
            textBox2.Text += " " + line;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide required details but are you looking for something like that; (writing the texts as lines to a file and reading it)

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextWriter txt = new StreamWriter(@"d:\\demo.txt", append: true);
        txt.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
        txt.Close();
    }
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\\demo.txt").Where(x => x.StartsWith("A"));
        textBox2.Text = string.Join(",", lines);
    }
```